# How to separate two Low[1] by if statement?

Tags: mql4

Example, previous low is 1.55. When next candle low is 1.66, then next next candle low is 1.44 which is lower than previous low (1.55) then do something. How to achieve it?

```
double previous_low = 0;
double new_low = 0;
double new_low2 = 0;
if (((previous_low==0)&&(Low[1] < Low[2])){
     previous_low = Low[1];
}
if (previous_low != 0){
     if (Low[1] < previous_low){
          new_low2 = Low[1]; //it fail
     }
     if (Low[0] < previous_low){
          new_low2 = Low[0]; //it works only if next 1 candle is lower than previous. It fail if next 2 candle is lower than previous_low.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It can be achive by bubblesort

```
 public class BubbleSort 
    { 
        void bubbleSort(double arr[]) 
        { 
            int n = arr.length; 
            for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
                for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) 
                    if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
                    { 
                         System.out.print("first value :"+arr[j]+" greater than" +"previos :"+arr[j+1] + " ");
                          System.out.println(); 
                        // swap arr[j+1] and arr[i] 
                        double temp = arr[j]; 
                        arr[j] = arr[j+1]; 
                        arr[j+1] = temp; 
                    } 
        } 

        /* Prints the array */
        void printArray(double arr[]) 
        { 
            int n = arr.length; 
            for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) 
                System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); 
            System.out.println(); 
        } 

        // Driver method to test above 
        public static void main(String args[]) 
        { 
            BubbleSort ob = new BubbleSort(); 
            double arr[] = {1.66, 1.55, 1.44}; 
            ob.bubbleSort(arr); 
            System.out.println("Sorted array"); 
            ob.printArray(arr); 
        } 
    }
```